# Retrieve OBJECTID from query result from GISServer

Tags: arcgis-server, objectid

Is there any way to obtain the OBJECTID value from returned result from GISServer query?

For example:

```
var searchString = "OBJECTID = 0001 OR OBJECTID = 0002";
var queryTask = new esri.tasks.QueryTask(url);
var queryParams = new esri.tasks.Query();
queryParams.outSpatialReference = new esri.SpatialReference({ wkid: xxxx });
queryParams.returnGeometry = true;
queryParams.where = searchString;
queryTask.execute(queryParams, resultsCallback, errorCallback);
```

If the returned result from above queryTask.execute() has only one feature, how do I know it is OBJECTID 0001 or OBJECTID 0002?

Of course..I can do the query one by one, but I am just wondering if there is better way to do it.

Comment: The SQL standard permits `OBJECTID in (1, 2)`.  You haven't specified which data format is in use, so the exact limit on `in` list count is uncertain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `QueryTask's` [executeForIds](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/querytask-amd.html#executeforids) method instead.

> *executeForIds(parameters, callback?, errback?)*
>
> Executes a Query against an ArcGIS Server map layer. The result is an
>   array of object IDs for features that satisfy the input query.

---

Otherwise, you need to be sure to set your `outFields` in the `queryParams`. Then you can loop through the returned `FeatureSet` and get the `ObjectIDs`.

```
query.outFields = ["ObjectID"]
queryTask.execute(query, showResults);

function showResults(featureSet) {
    //remove all graphics on the maps graphics layer
    map.graphics.clear();

    //Performance enhancer - assign featureSet array to a single variable.
    var resultFeatures = featureSet.features;

    //Loop through each feature returned
    for (var i=0, il=resultFeatures.length; i<il; i++) {

        var objectid = resultFeatures[i].attributes["ObjectID"];
        console.log("This is ObjectID: " + objectid);

        var graphic = resultFeatures[i];
        graphic.setSymbol(symbol);

        //Set the infoTemplate.
        graphic.setInfoTemplate(infoTemplate);

        //Add graphic to the map graphics layer.
        map.graphics.add(graphic);
    }
}
```

The above code is from this [Using QueryTask, Query, and FeatureSet documentation](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jshelp/intro_querytask.html) with an addition to grab the `ObjectID`.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention I still need the FeatureSet for drawing purpose. I wonder if the return result for both execute() and executeForIds() are always in sequence. (So I can just map the result array from both call)

Comment: @user3754580 here's a codepen example. It queries a map service, and returns the geometry (red boxes) and logs the FID's to the console: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gPMXZM

Comment: If the map in the codepen link above doesn't work, then make sure all the services in the Javascript are using https.